# having only the "Y" and "N" keys make the while loop function

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

How do I make it so this loop only repeats if the "N" key is hit. Currently, it will exit when I hit "Y", and will clear and continue the game if I hit "N", but it will also continue if I hit any other key?

```
while (cont)
{
    theUI.InScreen();
    goodBye.ClosingMessage();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit Y/N?");
    string exitInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (exitInput == "Y")
    {
        cont = false;
    }

    if (exitInput == "N")
    {
        cont = true;
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: please include the current code

Comment: just updated with current code my bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like this:

```
cont = true;
while (cont)
{
    theUI.InScreen();
    goodBye.ClosingMessage();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit Y/N?");
    string exitInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (exitInput.ToLower() == "y")
    {
        cont = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```

This way, if you hit "y" or "Y" the game will exit. Otherwise, it will continue to loop. You don't need to set `cont` to `true` again, because it doesn't change.